# can decimal column preserve precision and scale of inserted value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

If I insert some numbers of varying scale,such as 2.30, 2.3, into a decimal(20,8) column, when I read it back from DB, can I still get different scale?

I'v tried in SQL Server and Oracle. In SQL server what I got is 2.30000000 and 2.30000000,
and in Oracle  it's 2.3 and 2.3.

Is there a configuration or something can enable the DB preserve the scale of inserted values?

Comment: No. You need to format the value on your client application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, DB columns don't store a value's prior type. You could save these values as text so as to preserve the precision/scale, or you could save the precision/scale of the original value in a second column.

This is actually a common problem (and these are common solutions) in most engineering domains, where the precision of the measurement is just as important a piece of information as is the measurement itself.